# What is the meaning of Ω.mi?

Tags: transmission-line

In transmission line I see Ω.mi.

I know that Ω/mi gives the value of impedance per mile.

But Ω.mi gives impedance times mile!!

Assume a conductor has z = 1 Ω.mi

For a transmission line of 10 miles

total impedance = 1 Ω.mi / 10 mi = 0.1 Ω

For a transmission line of 1 mile of the same conductor type

total impedance = 1 Ω.mi / 1 mi = 1 Ω

How is it that the impedance of "1" mile is 10 times the impedance of "10" miles?

Comment: It's probably referring to conductivity (conductance per mile) i.e. G in the transmission line. This, of course becomes ohm-miles when inverted to find resistivity.

Answer (score 1):

The differential contribution of the dielectricum/isolation between the lines is not in series (like the contribution of the conductor) but in parallel.

The transmission line matrices contain (in different places) both the series contributions as well as the parallel contributions.